# Passing List to another GameObject script, it becomes empty after first operation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move a GameObject along a path by stages. Conceptually a first script, connected to the controller, defines the path via a List of Vector3 and a second one connected to the object moves it. To move it first rotates to face the destination and then it simply moves by incrementing transform.position by small steps.
The problem is that once the first part of the path has been completed the rest seems to cancel out (the Count became 0) and the robot stops.
This only happens by giving the list from a second script, trying it with a pre-defined list in the same script works fine.

This is the motion code:

```
public List<Vector3> pathRover;
[SerializeField] private float roverSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float roverRotateSpeed;
private float dotto;
private bool isRotating = false;
private bool isLerping = false;
private Vector3 startPosition;
private Vector3 targetPosition;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isRotating)
    {
        //To determine whether the robot faces the direction of movement
        dotto = Vector3.Dot(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), (new Vector3(targetPosition.x, 0, targetPosition.z) - new Vector3(startPosition.x, 0, startPosition.z)).normalized);

        if (dotto < 0.98f) // rotate until reached then move
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Time.deltaTime * roverRotateSpeed, 0);
            Debug.Log(dotto);
        }
        else
        {
            isLerping = true;
            isRotating = false;
        }
    }
    else if (isLerping)
    {
        var step = roverSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
        
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) <= 1f)
        {
            NextStep();
        }
    }
}

public void StartMoving(List<Vector3> pathReceived)
{
    if (pathReceived.Count > 1)
    {
        pathRover.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < pathReceived.Count; i++)
        {
            pathRover.Add(pathReceived[i]);
        }
        startPosition = transform.position;
        targetPosition = new Vector3(pathRover[0].x, pathRover[0].y + 0.7f, pathRover[0].z); //0.7f for the height of the rover from the ground
        isRotating = true;
    }
    else
    {
        StopMoving();
    }
}


public void StopMoving()
{
    isRotating = false;
    isLerping = false;
    pathRover.Clear();
}


public void NextStep()
{
    isLerping = false;
    StartMoving(pathRover);
}
```

From the other script:

```
roverMover.StartMoving(percorsoList);
```

No error appears in the debug console, I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: When do you call StartMoving when you run it with a predefined list in the same script?

Comment: I tried and so the loop works normally. I don't understand why it doesn't work by initializing it from another script.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are starting the move right at the `Start` of the script but you call `StartMoving` after a while. You have to move only when `StartMove` is called.

```
 public List<Vector3> pathRover;
    [SerializeField] private float roverSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float roverRotateSpeed;
    private float dotto;
    private bool isRotating = false;
    private bool isLerping = false;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    
    boolean startMove = false;
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
       if(startMove)
         Move();
    }
    
    public void Move(){
    
    if (isRotating)
        {
            //To determine whether the robot faces the direction of movement
            dotto = Vector3.Dot(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), (new Vector3(targetPosition.x, 0, targetPosition.z) - new Vector3(startPosition.x, 0, startPosition.z)).normalized);
    
            if (dotto < 0.98f) // rotate until reached then move
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, Time.deltaTime * roverRotateSpeed, 0);
                Debug.Log(dotto);
            }
            else
            {
                isLerping = true;
                isRotating = false;
            }
        }
        else if (isLerping)
        {
            var step = roverSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
            
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) <= 1f)
            {
                NextStep();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void StartMoving(List<Vector3> pathReceived)
    {
        startMove= true;
    
        if (pathReceived.Count > 1)
        {
            pathRover.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < pathReceived.Count; i++)
            {
                pathRover.Add(pathReceived[i]);
            }
            startPosition = transform.position;
            targetPosition = new Vector3(pathRover[0].x, pathRover[0].y + 0.7f, pathRover[0].z); //0.7f for the height of the rover from the ground
            isRotating = true;
        }
        else
        {
            StopMoving();
        }
    }
    
    
    public void StopMoving()
    {
        isRotating = false;
        isLerping = false;
        pathRover.Clear();
    }
    
    
    public void NextStep()
    {
        isLerping = false;
        StartMoving(pathRover);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried and it does not change the situation, unfortunately. Why is it better to start the movement later?